# How to disable ALT key?

Tags: macbook-pro

I would like to know how to permanently disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. I have a problem where by the computer is acting like the <kbd>Alt</kbd> is pressed down. Every time I type I get strange characters.

I have tried going into the keyboard preferences and disabling the <kbd>Option</kbd> key but that don't seem to be working. I disabled the <kbd>Alt</kbd> in the past this way and it worked. When I open the keyboard viewer it's showing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> as being pressed down.

This is a 2011 Macbook Air. I can't afford a repair at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that because the ALT key was stuck when disabling it, it had no effect. So, I bashed the keys and ran my fingers over them frantically and it unstuck the ALT key. I then went in and disabled it, and all is working fine.

Sometimes we have to go back to caveman tactics to solve these technological problems. If it don't work, bash it with the club.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have tried using a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
    <!--<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>-->>
  </item>
</root>
```

System Preferences also allows disabling modifier keys, but there is no way disable the left and right modifier keys separately:

[image]